# Voxel size tag from multipage TIFF images

Tags: c++, tiff, libtiff

I am trying to save a 3D volume image with anisotropic voxel dimensions as a multipage tiff file. The Tiff tags have an XResolution and a YResolution tag for the X and Y dimensions. However, I can't find anything for ZResolution. Which TIFF tag stores the ZResolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 3D standard in TIFF and you won't find a tag in the standard to do what you want. Some viewers interpret multipage TIFFs as 3D images but there is no portable format or tags.  Look at [ImageJ](https://imagej.net) for one such viewer, though I don't know that you can specify a ZResolution.